# Remove left margin/padding in ExpanderView

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-7.1

By default implementing a ExpanderView in an application the UI renders and the expanderView control has this left margin applied to it, some sort of indentation. It's rather stupid really that it's like that by default.

Is there some way to get rid of that margin and just that the control float completely to the left?

Also, how does one add some text to the expanders rectangle? No such property available.

Comment: I tried putting a minus margin, which did work. But the expader then completely just stopped working...

Comment: You're assuming that your answer worked for me. I haven't tested your given solution yet, but I have awarded you the bounty anyway.

Comment: No need to award anything if your question wasn't answered. Defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to edit the Control Template for the Expander. If you have Expression Blend it makes it quick and easy. You would just right-click your Expander on the artboard, choose "Edit Template" and then choose to either edit the current one, or a copy you could make and maybe put in a separate resource dictionary. Here's an example template. **Notice the 11,0,0,0 Margin on the itemsCanvas towards the bottom?** You can use this same method for editing just about any controls template. :)

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderViewStyle1" TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseInOut" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="41"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Collapsed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Expanded">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0"/>
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="CollapsedToExpandedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="1"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Collapsed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="ExpandedToCollapsedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1"/>
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1.0"/>
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.0"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0.0"/>
                                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-35"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandabilityStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Expandable"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NonExpandable">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandableContent">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="Line">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NonExpandableContent">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ListBoxItem x:Name="ExpandableContent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="41"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="Header" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="Expander" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ExpanderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Expander}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="11,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    <Grid x:Name="ExpanderPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <Line x:Name="Line" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" StrokeThickness="3" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="1"/>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="NonExpandableContent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeader}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <Canvas x:Name="ItemsCanvas" Grid.Column="1" Margin="11,0,0,0" Opacity="0.0" Grid.Row="2">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform TranslateY="0.0"/>
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="Presenter"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Either way, once you find the control template its quick and painless. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's late but maybe it will help somebody. I remove that margin in this style. I deleted columns from default grid. Moreover I create it as Wrap panel. It can be modified in ItemsPanelTemplate.

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderViewStyle" TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:ExpanderView">
              <Grid>
                  <Grid.Resources>
                      <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                      <QuadraticEase x:Key="QuadraticEaseInOut" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                  </Grid.Resources>
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
                          <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                              <VisualTransition From="Collapsed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Expanded">
                                  <Storyboard>
                                      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0"/>
                                          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="CollapsedToExpandedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="1"/>
                                      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                      <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                  </Storyboard>
                              </VisualTransition>
                              <VisualTransition From="Expanded" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Collapsed">
                                  <Storyboard>
                                      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="ExpandedToCollapsedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1"/>
                                          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                                      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="1.0"/>
                                          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0.0"/>
                                      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas">
                                          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0.0"/>
                                          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseInOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-35"/>
                                      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                  </Storyboard>
                              </VisualTransition>
                          </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                          <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                          <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                      </VisualStateGroup>
                      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandabilityStates">
                          <VisualState x:Name="Expandable"/>
                          <VisualState x:Name="NonExpandable">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandableContent">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NonExpandableContent">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                      </VisualStateGroup>
                  </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <ListBoxItem x:Name="ExpandableContent" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                      <Grid>
                          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <ContentControl x:Name="Header" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"/>
                          <ContentControl x:Name="Expander" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ExpanderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Expander}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"/>
                          <Grid x:Name="ExpanderPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                      </Grid>
                  </ListBoxItem>

                  <ContentControl x:Name="NonExpandableContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding NonExpandableHeader}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                  <Canvas x:Name="ItemsCanvas" Opacity="0.0" Grid.Row="2">
                      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                          <CompositeTransform TranslateY="0.0"/>
                      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                      <ItemsPresenter x:Name="Presenter"/>
                  </Canvas>
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```